# Codeigniter: Passing Data to View Undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i pass `$data` from controller to view, show me this error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/admin.php
>
> Line Number: 10

My Controller

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->is_logged_in())
        {
          $data['login'] = $this->session->userdata('login');        
          $this->load->view('admin',$data['login']);
        }else
        {
          $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }

    public function login()
    {

        $this->load->model('usuario');
        $resultado = $this->usuario->validate();

        if($resultado)
        {
            $dados = array(
                    'login' => $this->input->post('login'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );

            $this->session->set_userdata($dados);
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('fadas');
        }


    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        return $this->session->all_userdata();
    }
```

and my View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Panel - Sistema de Controle de Indicações de Vereadores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
             <?php echo $data['login']; ?> </p> 
        </nav>  
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

ty :)

Comment: How are you implementing sessions?

Comment: Yeap, but when you say "implementing" you say about autoload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass $data, not $data['login']. Then access it via $login.

Code below:

Controller:

```
$this->load->view('admin',$data);
```

View:

```
<?php echo $login ?> </p>
```